# draw a line chart using big array in highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to draw a line chart using big array list of objects with id,named values but something is going wrong. I can see following warnings in firebug window :

```
Unexpected value NaN parsing y attribute.
elem[setAttribute](prop, value);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stGXM/19/

Why do those warnings are coming? Currently chart is not getting drawn even though I have mentioned all the necessary values.

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

You should specify each point in your series in the form [x, y, ID].

I've modified your code: http://jsfiddle.net/Ut5C3/

Here's the Highcharts reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.type

Comment: You remove id's from array! I need id's for sync data to my jqgrid.
my code work with less array but with big array I have this problem!

Comment: I've added the IDs as the third element in each data point array. The jsfiddle example has been updated. I'll leave it as an exercise for you to extract this and sync to your grid.

Comment: Id's not set for points, I think must be use array object with key and value for setting points id's!

Comment: The answer is :
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold